# Were there any major battles between Australian Aborigines and English Colonists?

Tags: colonization, australia, battle, aboriginals

The English were hostile to most of the natives near their colonies. However, I can't seem to find any evidence as to whether or not the Aborigines partook in any battle against British colonists in Australia. Was there any ***MAJOR*** coordinated conflict between the two peoples?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_frontier_wars

Comment: Do you mean battle as in a coordinated conflict, or a battle as in any conflict? The question title/body should be synchronised to one or other meanings.

Comment: @LateralFractal Coordinated Conflict.

Comment: Trivial, see Lennart's complete answer by basic encyclopaedic searching.

Comment: @SamuelRussell The question as worded is *probably* covered (with some digging) in the Wikipedia article cited. But the question almost but not quite touches on a much more interesting vein of enquiry: The Australian [History Wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_wars) regarding the level and nature of the conflict.

Comment: So I'm upvoting this one if simply because the current http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_frontier_wars article doesn't go out of its way to highlight if any major coordinated conflicts occurred and which, when and where they were. Of course on the flipside - does the very Eurocentric idea of "major conflict" render the question subjective? I'm sure the natives considered it major regardless of set piece battles.

Comment: IIRC, sustained low-intensity warfare in the now Sydney basin brought the first fleet near to starvation.  The question fetishises the tactical.

Comment: Cannot support re-open without evidence of preliminary research